# Continuity of zeros of a parametrized family of functions.

Tags: analysis

Say we have a family of functions $f_a$ on $[0,\infty]$ and suppose that each of them has a unique zero at $z_a$. Are there general conditions of $f_a$ that can ensure that $z_a$ is continuous in $a$?

Comment: Continuity of the function $F(z, \alpha) = f_\alpha(z)$ suffices.